# Disk space lost after quitting disk partition

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

My MacBook Pro came with a 500 GB hard disk, and I used about 250 GB.
I was trying to get a new logic partition using the OSX disk utility, and then my Mac Book Pro froze and I had to quit the Disk Utility.

Then the available space just disappeared.

- Disk Utility shows that the **logic partition** has a total capacity of 498.88 GB, available 10.48 GB, used 243.75 GB, which does not add up.
- Disk Utility shows that the **hard drive** has a total capacity of 499.25 GB, available 19 MB, used 499.23 GB.
- running `df -h` shows

  ```
  Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused   ifree %iused  Mounted on 
  /dev/disk1     237Gi  227Gi  9.8Gi    96%   59509256      2559899 96%   /
  ```

Things I have tried:

- all check and repair functions in Disk Utility
- `fsck -f`
- reboot and cmd+R and open the command line  tool, but I cannot mount /dev/disk0 with `-t hfs`. It tells me `resource busy`

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0`, `diskutil list` and `diskutil cs list` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You probably tried to manipulate a CoreStorage volume with Disk Utility. Core Storage volumes are built after enabling File Vault 2, creating a Fusion Drive or often after updating to Yosemite.

If you don't have a second internal hard disk attached, disk0 is usually mounted to /. In your case disk1 is mounted to / which is a typical hint for Core Storage Volume Group - in case of an internal Fusion Drive disk2 is mounted to / and disk0 and disk1 usually don't appear entering `df -h`.

Open Terminal and enter `diskutil cs list` to get all CoreStorage objects in a tree-like view.

Use [this](http://blog.fosketts.net/2011/08/05/undocumented-corestorage-commands/) comprehensive list of documented and undocumented commands to manipulate your CoreStorage Volume Group.